# Using ngSwitch on a numeric range in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, ng-switch

I have recently started learning Angular2.

I want to know if there is a possibility to use ngSwitch or ngIf angular2

directives for a specific numeric range?

Say I want to update the color of some text based on a range.

```
<25 = Mark the text in red
>25 && <75 = Mark the text in orange
>75 = Mark the text in green
```

How do I achieve the same using Angular2 ngIf/ngSwitch directives.

Is there a way something to write like this ?

```
<div [ngIf]="item.status < 25">
<h2 class="text-red">{{item.status}}</h2>
</div>
<div [ngIf]="item.status > 25 && item.status < 75">
<h2 class="headline text-orange">{{item.status}}</h2>
</div>
<div [ngIf]="item.status > 75">
<h2 class="headline text-green">{{item.status}}</h2>
</div>
```

Or anything that would have to do with using ngSwitch, ngSwitchWhen statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `*ngIf` you would do it like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="item.status < 25">
    <h2 class="headline text-red">{{item.status}}</h2>
</div>
<div *ngIf="item.status > 25 && item.status < 75">
    <h2 class="headline text-orange">{{item.status}}</h2>
</div>
<div *ngIf="item.status > 75">
    <h2 class="headline text-green">{{item.status}}</h2>
</div>
```

With `[ngSwitch]` the syntax is like this:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="true">
    <h2 *ngSwitchCase="item.status < 25" class="headline text-red">{{item.status}}</h2>
    <h2 *ngSwitchCase="item.status > 25 && item.status < 75" class="headline text-orange">{{item.status}}</h2>
    <h2 *ngSwitchDefault class="headline text-green">{{item.status}}</h2>
</div>
```

Quick notes

- The old `*ngSwitchWhen` now works as `*ngSwitchCase`
- Cases like `item.status > 75` and above are automatically handled by `*ngSwitchDefault`

Answer (score 2):

This might work, but I haven't tried it myself:

```ts
<div [ngSwitch]="value">
  <p *ngSwitchCase="'init'">increment to start</p>
  <p *ngSwitchCase="item.status < 25 ? value">a</p>
  <p *ngSwitchCase="item.status > 25 && item.status < 75 ? value ">c</p>
  <p *ngSwitchCase="item.status > 75 ? value">d</p>
  <p *ngSwitchDefault>else</p>
</div>
```

The idea is that when the expression is true, then return `value` for `*ngSwitchWhen` to match the `[ngSwitch]` value.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you move the logic to the component, you'll have less boilerplate, and it's easier to work with:

```
<div>
  <h2 [class]="switchClass(item.status)">{{item.status}}</h2>
</div>

switchClass(item.status) {
  if (item.status < 25) return "text-red";
  else if (25 < items.status && item.status < 75) return "headline text-orange";
  else if (75 < items.status) return "headline text-green";
}
```

Although you can write:

```
<div *ngIf="(item.status > 25) && (item.status < 75)">
```

Answer (score 0):

In dealing with angular2 conditional styling it's best to use `[class]` when you are adding a single class or `[ngClass]` when you are returning an array of classes like so: `headline text-green someOtherClass`.

```
// display div
<div [ngClass]="getItemClass(item.status)">{{item.status}}</div>

// logic
getItemClass(status) {
  let itemClass: string;

  if (status < 25) {
    itemClass = 'text-red';
  } else if (status > 25 && status < 75) {
    itemClass = 'headline text-orange';
  } else {
    itemClass = 'headline text-green';
  }

  return itemClass;
}
```

Similarly, instead of declaring `itemClass` as a string, we could declare it as an array, i.e `let itemClass: Array<string>;` in which case we reassign it in our if blocks as `itemClass = ['headline', 'text-green']`. This works just as fine.